# Silent runtime error with 2D arrays

Tags: c++

I'm creating 2D arrays, with the structure of an static array with dynamic arrays. The code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

#define MAT_SIZE 100000

typedef float* DynMat[MAT_SIZE];

int main()
{
   int r, c;

   DynMat matDyn, matDynAns;

   for (r = 0; r < MAT_SIZE; r++)
   {
      matDyn[r] = new float[MAT_SIZE];
      matDynAns[r] = new float[MAT_SIZE];
      for (c = 0; c < MAT_SIZE; c++)
      {
         matDyn[r][c] = 0;
         matDynAns[r][c] = 0;
      }
   }

   cout << "hello" << endl;
}
```

I believe there is a silent runtime error being thrown during my initialization of the matrices, because the code compiles and runs, yet nothing is printed.

Comment: There is a very big error in your code. But besides that, what do you mean nothing is printed? There is no printing in your code (except for the last line).

Comment: @DeiDei Yes, even the last line does not print. There is no "hello" being printed.

Comment: why not run under a debugger and break in. look at r and c and see how far it has got. Or simply do a cout each time your main loop. it will be an eyeopener for you

Comment: @cfire19045 what OS are you running on?

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Windows 10

Comment: thats a lot of stack too, 200k pointers

Comment: Being pedantic here, but what you have is an array of arrays. These can have pretty horrible effects on cache use because each row is potentially scattered throughout memory. I wouldn't worry about it here though, not with a 400000 byte row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program *gradually* allocates 80 GB of memory.  It’s not printing anything because it’s swapping forever instead.  (This is similar to [thrashing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)), but instead of repeatedly loading a “few” pages it’s just linearly filling many of them.)

Comment: Is the issue of memory not solved by using dynamic arrays as my rows?

Comment: @cfire19045: Do you or do you not have ~100 GB of physical memory?  Dynamic allocation can’t help if you don’t.

Comment: no its not, no matter how you slice it 80gb is 80gb, thats a lot of memory.

Comment: Yes, I have almost 900 GB free on the computer. The compiler allocates the memory on the computer, not the flash drive I am saving my program in, correct? Also, is this RAM or hard drive memory?

Comment: Also it might exhibit stack overflow

Comment: we are talking about ram, no windows 10 machine has a terabyte of ram

Comment: @pm100 Yup, I definitely have less than 80 GB of RAM. I just realized that I had set MAT_SIZE much too high; it was intended to be 10,000, which resolves the issue.